# Rails - Skip rails validation for subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a User class, and a Contact where Contact is a subclass of User. Both classes are stored in a users table.

My Contacts may or may not have an email address, while an email address is required for my Users (I have `validates_presence_of :email` in my User model definition).

My reasoning is that Contacts are entered by users and may later become Users when they claim their profile.

- First of all, is it ok to define my
  users and contacts the way I did it?
- Second, how do I skip the
  `validate_presence_of email`
  validation in my contacts model?

(I'm on rails 2.3.8)

Thanks!

UPDATE:

- It seems Single Table Inheritance is
  designed to do exactly what I needed
- the right way to skip validation for
  the presence of email for my Contact
  table is as follow:

`validates_presence_of :email, :unless => Proc.new {|user| user.type == "Contact"}`

Comment: Shouldn't User be a subclass of Contact?  It seems to me that a User *is a* Contact who registered.  But a Contact isn't necessarily a User.  This would also solve your validation problem, since the validation would go in the User model, negating the need for an :unless clause.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds like you should abstract out User and Contacts into two tables instead of trying to consolidate them into one. Although contacts *can* become users, that doesn't mean that they will (I think?).

This would also solve your `validate_presence_of :email` question, as the contact table/model wouldn't even have the field. It would also alleviate potential performance concerns later on, I believe. You wouldn't want to have a ton of contacts to sort through to find a registered user.

If you're dead-set on doing it in one table though, I believe you can do something like the following:

`validates_presence_of :email, :unless => Proc.new {|user| user.type == "Contact"}`

This is assuming that you have a user_type column, but you could replace that depending on how you're determining whether a `User` is a `Contact`.

**Update**:

This is how you'd correctly validate the models: Remove the `validates_presence_of` from the model and place it inside of this block:

```
with_options :unless => :user_type == "contact" do |user|
   user.validates_presence_of :email
end
```

Comment: I currently have a "user_type" field in my users table that says whether the row is for a user or a contact. Having both in the same table makes it easier for me to transform a contact into a user when they claim their profile. And all the fields are similar, only the validation on email is different. That's why I'd like to use the same table.

Any clue how I could bypass the validation for the email field (alternatively, I can do Contact.save(false), but it skips all validations, not just the email.

Comment: I understand that and it's not necessarily a bad way to do things. To my understanding, users could potentially have hundreds of contacts that wouldn't necessarily be registered users. If your site grew to 100,000 users, think of the performance implications of consolidating that into one table. Although it's not a problem currently, it would be more of a hassle to switch it if that ever occurs then just doing the design change now. You're essentially trading more database calls for not having a potentially huge table.

Comment: Also, look at my updated answer. The `validates_presence_of :email unless...` bit should work, if memory serves me correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I couldn't get it to work with `with_options` but it works fine with `unless` (the exact syntax is: `validates_presence_of :email, :unless => Proc.new {|user| user.type == "Contact"}`. Also, I renamed `user_type` to `type` so I can use a Single Table Inheritance which I believe is designed to do exactly what I want... I'm keeping it this way for now... maybe will add a Contact table later... don't have time to make the changes now.

Comment: No problem man. I hadn't tried `with_options`, it was just something I found on the internet that seemed pertinent. I'm glad you got it working though, I'll update the answer to reflect your fix.